# GREP to find a sequence of characters without a closing apostrophe

Tags: grep, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I'm trying to find long quotes in the text that I'm editing so that I can apply a different style to them. I've tried this GREP:

~[.{230}(?!.~])

What I need is for the GREP to find any 230 characters preceded by a left/opening quote mark, not including any 230-character sequence including a character followed by a right/clsoing quote mark. This should then eliminate quotes of less than 230 characters from the search. My GREP finds the correct length sequence but doesn't exclude those sequences which include a right quote mark.

So I want to find this, which my GREP does:

[image]

But not this, which my GREP also finds:

[image]

Because it has a closing quote in it and is therefore what I'm classing as a short quote.

Any ideas? TIA

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew is this clearer?

Comment: Try it like this `~[^~]{1,230}` https://regex101.com/r/vuJBaL/1 Or with `grep -oP` and a lookahead `~[^~]{1,230}(?=~)` https://regex101.com/r/anqlNa/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks, but doesn't seem to work. I'm beginning to think it's not possible to use GREP to find a sequence of 230 characters preceded by an opening apostrophe but not including a closing apostrophe

Comment: Quotation mark, like this `‘[^‘’]{1,230}(?=’)` https://regex101.com/r/zdcqh2/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Okay, that does the opposite, so almost there. It finds all quotes under 230 characters

Comment: If you want 230 or more characters `‘[^‘’]{230,}(?=’)` https://regex101.com/r/XREbXD/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match an opening `‘` followed by 230 or more occurrences of any character except an opening or closing quotation mark.

To not match the closing quotation mark, you can assert it using a positive lookahead.

```
‘[^‘’]{230,}(?=’)
```

- `‘` Match `‘`
- `[^‘’]{230,}` Repeat 230+ times any char except `‘` or `’` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `(?=’)` Positive lookahead, assert `’` directly to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xRThJf/1).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Thefourthbird.

So what I needed was:

```
‘[^’]{230,}
```

to search for an opening apostrophe ‘ followed by anything but a closing apostrophe [^’] of 230 characters or more {230,}

Strangely, if you use InDesign's code for left ~[ and right ]~ apostrophe it doesn't work!

Comment: Just realised it doesn't work if there is a possessive apostrophe in the quote. i.e. it will see 'Charles's poodles' as the quote prematurely ending after 'Charles'. I don't suppose you can say unless there is a comma/full stop/exclamation point/question mark followed by an apostrophe?

I tried:

    ‘[^.’|,’|?’|!’]{230,}